# Where are compiled SCSS files in a GEM stored?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, asset-pipeline

I include in my project a GEM which in it has (under /vendor/assets/stylesheets) a 'src'-directory with some SCSS files.

In development mode, when these scss files are compiled to css, where are they (the css files) stored? I can find nothing under neither "vendor" nor "lib". In tmp?

The reason I ask is that one "*= require" fails and since it references a scss file in the gem I want to know what is happening.

Comment: Sass libraries typically do not have files that will be compiled into CSS, they're usually all prefixed with an underscore.

Comment: yes well it turned out that this was a bug. Apparently I was supposed to require 'src/theutility' and not require 'theutility'. I was a bit unsure about the inner workings of the asset pipeline and therefore asked the question. My theory is that in development mode, the scss is compiled to a temporary file (each time or cached?) before sent to the client. In production it is compiled once to public/assets, am I right?

Comment: ..and it was not a sass library, it was a GEM with an included scss file that I had to require.